# Correct way to Vertically & Horizontally center all images in table cells html

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a table with a html page (it will be a products page).

The first cell of each row has a image but no text (which is a fixed size) and I need to center the image Vertically & Horizontally. The first row with the column names obviously does not have an image. There will be many rows, each with a different image in the first cell and I want to apply the "center V&H" to all of them.

I have spent literately hours each day for a week trying to find the answer that works for my code below and I have searched and tried all suggestions on here in other posts but it has beaten me hence asking here.

I am currently trying table img {align: center; vealign: center;} but this does not work. I have also tried all the different variations that I can find on the web but with no luck.

Also I am using  as there will be more than one table and each table will have different column widths.

I am no expert so be kind but I am learning..

```
<style>
table {width:100%;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
table tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #ebebeb; color: black}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #ffffff; color: black}
table th {background-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold;}
table img {align: center; vealign: center;}
th, td {padding: 5px; text-align: left;}

</style>
<body>

<table id="t01">
  <col width="10%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="30%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
<tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>  
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
    <th>Heading 5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ><img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6216/lOGXW9.jpg" /></td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ... <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.        </td>
    <td>More Text</td>
    <td>Yet More Text</td>
    <td>Even More Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6216/lOGXW9.jpg" /></td>
<td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ... <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.</td>
<td>More Text</td>
<td>Yet More Text</td>
<td>Even More Text</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: In the css, replace [table img {align: center; vealign: center;}] with table img {margin:0px auto;}.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is for the table cells to have a default of `text-align: left` and `vertical-align: top`.

Since the first `td` element in a row is the first child of the `tr` element, you can use the `first-child` selector to apply `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle` to position the image.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:first-child

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: black
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black
}
table th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
td:first-child {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="t01">
  <col width="10%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="30%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
    <th>Heading 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6216/lOGXW9.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ...
      <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.</td>
    <td>More Text</td>
    <td>Yet More Text</td>
    <td>Even More Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x70" />
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ...
      <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.</td>
    <td>More Text</td>
    <td>Yet More Text</td>
    <td>Even More Text</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion and it seems to solve all of the problems I was having.I will read the reference you suggested as I would not have been able to work this out on my own, i just do not have the skill.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please accept so that the community can move on.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Will this solve your problem?

**HTML**

```
<table id="t01">
  <col width="10%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="30%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
<tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>  
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
    <th>Heading 5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ><img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6216/lOGXW9.jpg" /></td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ... <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.        </td>
    <td>More Text</td>
    <td>Yet More Text</td>
    <td>Even More Text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><img src="http://www.pedromoneo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/coca-cola.jpg" /></td>
<td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ... <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.</td>
<td>More Text</td>
<td>Yet More Text</td>
<td>Even More Text</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, tr, td
{
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}

td:first-child
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

img
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8nvqwm4/1/)

I updated the CSS to position the image centered both vertically and horizontally for the first column (the image column) the others are set to be vertically aligned top and text-left to right.

In this case I simply selected the first child of `<td>` which would be the first column containing your images and set the css properties for that element, then I set default settings for all others.

You can remove the border if you wish, its just for clarity.

Comment: The only thing changed from your original code is CSS :) good luck

Comment: This also works really well so now I have decide which of the two suggestions is the best one to use.

Comment: Okay, I have spoken too soon. All of the cell contents on all rows and columns are being centered including text in the columns without an image. I need *only* the images (which are in column 1) V&H centered but the text in the other columns to be aligned left?

Comment: @FreeChoice Apologies for the late reply, I have updated my answer to what you require, I also have to apologise for misunderstanding the question, something that you will encounter a lot on Stack Overflow. I updated the CSS and Fiddle demo for you to check it works :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
td { text-align: center;}
```

or inline only for `td` which contains image

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: black
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black
}
table th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
td:first-child {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="t01">
  <col width="10%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="30%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <col width="20%"></col>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
    <th>Heading 3</th>
    <th>Heading 4</th>
    <th>Heading 5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6216/lOGXW9.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ...
      <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.</td>
    <td>More Text</td>
    <td>Yet More Text</td>
    <td>Even More Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x70" />
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br />Nam dolor odio, lacinia in ...
      <br>Pellentesque ac enim vitae lorem aliquet pretium.</td>
    <td>More Text</td>
    <td>Yet More Text</td>
    <td>Even More Text</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```